# c# Winform Controls to VSTO Excel Addin How to get value back.

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, excel-addins

I am new to VSTO Excel Addin and I am looking to add Winform Control to VSTO project. Currently my addin has a ribbon and it has a button. Button click opens up a Windows form which has few check boxes and a "Done" button. Once user hits Done, I want to capture all check boxes chosen by the users.

This is how my ribbon looks:

[image]

"Split Data" is the button and its click even launches a Winform as shown below:

```
private void btnSpltData_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            FieldSelector fs = new FieldSelector();
            fs.ShowDialog();
        }
```

[image]

With Done button, I am closing the form. I can find out which checkBox was checked using checkbox.checked property, But I not sure how to send it back to btnSpltData_Click method in the ribbon.

How can I achieve that ? Any pointer?

```
private void buttonDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already show the form by calling `.ShowDialog();`, thats good, this will break the code at that line untill the form is closed. So just add a property to your Form that you can read afterwards. 
Small example:

```
public class Ribbon
{
    private void btnSpltData_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        FieldSelector fs = new FieldSelector();
        fs.ShowDialog();
        if (fs.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) // Did user press the 'done' button? or did they exit using X
        {
            foreach (var checkedField in fs.CheckedFields)
            {
                // do stuff with the value
            }
        }
    }
}
public class FieldSelector :  Form
{
    // A property to read after the form has closed
    public List<string> CheckedFields 
    { 
         get; 
    } = new List<string>(); // Never null

    private void buttonDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve all the Checkboxes that are a direct child of the form
        foreach (var control in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            if (control.Checked)
                CheckedFields.Add(control.Text); // Keep track of the Text value of the checked checkboxes
        }

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // just for being neat when using ShowDialog()
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation and code. This works great!

Comment: @ProgSky Well explained question and well explained response. I immensely benefited from both. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.